# Is this really an improvement (moving var to inner scope when inner scope is in a loop)?

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper, scope

Resharper recommends that these vars:

```
List<string> senderDeviceIDList;
string senderDeviceID;
. . .
            foreach (var item in PlatypiIds)
            {
                senderDeviceIDList = await GetSenderDeviceIDForSenderID(item);
                senderDeviceID = senderDeviceIDList[0];
```

...can be declared in inner scope, like so:

```
    foreach (var item in PlatypiIds)
    {
        List<string> senderDeviceIDList = await GetSenderDeviceIDForSenderID(item);
        string senderDeviceID = senderDeviceIDList[0];
```

...but is that really "more better"? Doesn't that cause the vars to be declared N times (once for each foreach loop)?

Comment: The compiler will optimize either way. This is more of a readability issue (and one that ensures variables are not reused where they shouldn't be).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is no **any** benefit in terms of performance or memory allocation here, as variables *inside* or *oustside* of the `if` scope are declared in the `IL`, by the way.

The only benefit is localization of the variable scope. Move it to the scope where it's used, which brings goodness like:

- easy refactoring (may be the most important)
- readability. If you see variable inside the scope, you know that its used *only* inside that scope and if you see some variable that apparently is not inside, you know that changing it can affect other parts of the code. So changing it introduce some *potential* danger.

In short, it's about readability and usability of the code you're writing and does not introduce any performance or memory consumption benefits.

Comment: +1 And reduces chance of variable re-use, which can be extremely unreadable and confusing.

Comment: Doesn't it also help with the contention caused by using the async/await (threading) functionality? I remember reading somewhere that moving the variables into the loop can help lower the contention between threads when spawned inside the loop (which this essentially is).. thereby improving performance slightly.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead No, not really.  In this case, given the use of `await`, a new class will be created that contains everything that's in this method and the local variables will become instance fields.

Comment: @Servy Ah. I should probably move on to 4.5 and learn the inner workings of async/await :) Thanks for the info.

Comment: One point missing: if you move it to an outer scope it can be used (and overwritten) also other scopes, so bugs are  more likely.

Answer (score 10):

> Doesn't that cause the vars to be declared N times (one for each foreach loop)?

Logically, from a conceptual point of view yes, **and that's the point**!  Logically they exist once per loop and make no sense outside of the scope of the loop.

As an implementation detail, no, it will not result in multiple local variables being created.  The method will only have a single variable and it will be re-used in the general case (and when it's allowed to).  There are exceptional cases, such as when you close over the variable with an anonymous method, in which it can't re-use a variable.

Note that because C# forces you to initialize all local variables before using them the runtime isn't even responsible for clearing it after each loop, the compiler won't let you re-use the garbage that was in the before (unless you explicitly initialize it at the start of the loop to the default value).

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning instances of those objects once per iteration anyways, the only thing that's different in the initial approach is that you are declaring the references once, rather than every iteration as in the 2nd example.

If you needed to use those objects in their final state at the end of the foreach loop (hairy), then you may want to go with the 1st approach.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes benefit exists.

If resulting array is huge, then moving it to the inner scope — i.e. reducing scope and lifetime — may prevent it to be shifted to later garbage collection generations, and to be garbage collected with a tangible delay.

---

*Decided to explain my old answer [after getting surprised by an upvote] and partially give up from my words (27.10.2021)*

**Detail #0.**
Two your options differ in visibility scope and, hence, lifetime. A variable declared inside "for" loop lives starting from the declaration until `}` of this loop, i.e. until the end of *each* iteration. *This means that the variable doesn't even exist after the end of each iteration until it reaches the declaration line of the next iteration!*

And a variable declared outside "for" loop lives for the entire duration of the method body (I assume here that in your first example it is declared at the top level of some method's body).

Ok, what it affects?

Variables may represent a pointer to an object. And objects live only when at least someone points at them. Because if no one points at them, how can anyone refer to them? And vice versa - if someone points to an object, it may refer to it at some point in the future, so it must live. That's exactly the logic of the garbage collector (GC).

So, when you leave the visibility scope of a variable, which points to some object, GC can stop taking this pointer into consideration. And if that object had only one pointer to itself (your variable), then this object already doesn't exist as no one points to it. However, it continues to live in terms of occupied memory - it's a garbage in your heap that waits for GC to be collected (at the next garbage collection run or later - it's up to GC when to free the memory).

Getting back to your options - there're points during the method execution when these options differ in terms of whether GC is allowed or not collecting an object to which your variable is/were pointing. As long as garbage collection may happen at any moment, moving a variable declaration to the inner scope just increases probability that that object could be collected.

Aaaaaand.. 99.9% of the time you should not worry about it, because this object will be collected at some point in the future anyway! *But..*

**Detail #1**

No "but". Really :)

Dunno, I probably was mistaken back in 2016 by thinking that objects in LOH (Large Object Heap) also have generations, so it does matter how quickly you can allow GC to collect them - because the higher the generation the more rare its collection happens. Therefore generation 2 objects are very-very long lived objects. This's not true now (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap)) - LOH objects are generation 2 objects for their entire lifetime. So, no rush with variables to LOH objects - you are already late :)

Even if these objects are large, but not large enough for LOH, you probably still should not worry until you find evidences that you have to investigate this matter (memory footprint and performance).

**The moral**
So, my answer should be *Sometimes benefit exists [but it's negligible].*

Specifying the right scope is a help to yourself and your teammates in the first place, not a fancy performance trick.